# How to make a page look like it would have w/o tpl

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

Say, for example, I want to customize the edit user page, so I have created a user-profile.tpl.php. Is there a way to echo out what the page would be normally? What variables should I have access to?

I have tried var_dumping `$node`, `$form`, `$page`, `$content`, and `$user_profile` and all but the last are null...

`print render($user_profile);` results in a list of profile fields, but not the edit-user page that I get without the tpl file.. (where you can change password, email, etc.

I'm curious for pages/nodes/etc in general, not just this particular one. It's an issue I always struggle with.

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1089656 should get you started, but if you are trying to modify what your user edit page would look like WITH a template, you'd use something along the lines of `page--user--edit.tpl.php`

Answer (score 2):

To see the array $var / $variable -

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($var); //or $variable whichever is applicable.
echo "</pre>";
```

This will output the entire $var/$variable array in structured manner and you can find out all the data available in your tpl.

Hope that is of some help...

Comment: You can also add a preprocess function and declare your own variables there in $var['example_var'] = _something_ and that will be available in your tpl as $example_var.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply open the default template (modules/user/user-profile.tpl.php in this case).

The comment at the top of the file should show the variables availible to you.